# Perl: elsif, Python: elif, C/ CPP/ Java: else if

Tags: perl, if-statement, compiler-errors, key, syntax-error

This was the code giving me errors on Perl.

---

```
...
else if (exists($framename{$presFrame}) && (($framename{$presFrame}) < = $j))
...
```

---

here `framename` is a hash and `presFrame` is a key present in `framename`

Edit:

Realized if/ else syntax is a bit different in Perl as mentioned in correct answer.

Comment: Try `<=` instead of `< =`.

Comment: sry but that didn't worked !!!1 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
elsif (exists($framename{$presFrame}) && (($framename{$presFrame}) <= $j))
```

otherwise you'd need braces on the else clause, i.e.

```
else {
  if(...) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
else if (exists($framename{$presFrame}) && (($framename{$presFrame}) < = $j))
```

Should be:

```
elsif (exists($framename{$presFrame}) && ($framename{$presFrame} < = $j))
```